# Federated AD - Change Azure Tenant

Tags: azure, directory, adfs, federated

Federated and Dirsync'd with on-premise Active Directory. Office 365 works great. Using Azure with co-administrators. Here begins the crux of the problem. Co-administrator added the federated domain to the Azure tenant. It showed up fine as a directory but no as *or* in the Default Directory for the tenant. Also can't seem to make any changes that would allow it to be the Default Directory. It doesn't appear that I can safely disassociate it since it seems that it would also undo the synchronization with O365's services. Also doesn't appear that I can do any sort of reciprocated access to the federated directory to allow me to assign users from that domain or even reference it in any way by the tenant's global administrator. The specific service we are trying to use is Azure RemoteApp. It only allows user assignment to be end users from the Default Directory and no other.

Is there any way to change the tenant with which a federated domain is associated without breaking the existing federation? ...to clarify the 1st paragraph, the federated domain in O365 is good. However, in Azure it is associated with the wrong tenant (Doh!) I can't take any action that would break the O365 federation. The fix may be much simpler than I'm making it but I can not currently see it...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Eric

Answer (score 1):

I'd forgotten about this question... While I was experienced with federation in O365, I was new with federation in Azure at the time. When I asked the question, I was still logged in with my Microsoft Account as opposed to a federated ID with Global access. Simply changing the account from which I was managing took care of my problem.